"Nullity in the Proof of Multiplicity in the Perron-Frobenius Theorem"

$\textbf{Theorem 26.4.}$ (Perron-Frobenius). $\,\, $If $A \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq}^{n \times n}$ is irreducible, then $A \neq O_{n \times n}$ and:

$(1)$ $\quad$ $r_{\sigma(A)} \in \sigma(A)$.
$(2)$ $\quad$ There exists a pair of vectors $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}_{>}^{n}$ such that
$$
A\mathbf{u} = r_{\sigma(A)}\mathbf{u}, \quad A^T\mathbf{v} = r_{\sigma(A)}\mathbf{v}, \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{u} = 1. \tag{26.7}$$
$(3)$ $\quad$ The algebraic multiplicity of $r_{\sigma(A)}$ as an eigenvalue of $A$ is equal to one.
$(4)$ $\quad$ If $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with nonnegative entries, then $A\mathbf{x} = r_{\sigma(A)}\mathbf{x}$.


3. $\quad$ The geometric multiplicity of } $r_{\sigma}(A)$ \textit{ as an eigenvalue of $A$ is equal to one.

Let $\mathbf{x} = [x_1 \cdots  x_n]^T$ and $\mathbf{y} = [y_1  \cdots  y_n]^T$ be any two nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $A\mathbf{x} = r_{\sigma}(A)\mathbf{x}$ and $A\mathbf{y} = r_{\sigma}(A)\mathbf{y}$. Then $y_1\mathbf{x} - x_1\mathbf{y}$ is also in the null space of the matrix $A - r_{\sigma}(A)I_n$. Thus, by step $2$, $x_1 \neq 0$, $y_1 \neq 0$, and either $y_1\mathbf{x} - x_1\mathbf{y} = 0$ or $|y_1x_j - x_1y_j| > 0$ for $j = 1, \ldots, n$. However, the second alternative is clearly impossible, since the first entry in the vector $y_1\mathbf{x} - x_1\mathbf{y}$ is equal to zero. Thus, $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are linearly dependent.


4. Verification of $(3)$.

Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$ repeated in accordance with their algebraic multiplicity, let $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy $(26.7)$, and let $\lambda_1 = \tau(\mathbf{A})$,
$$
\varphi(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_n - A), \quad \text{and} \quad \psi(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_n - [A - \lambda_1 \mathbf{uv}^T]).
$$

Then, since $(\lambda I_n - A)^{-1} \lambda_1 \mathbf{u} = (\lambda - \lambda_1)^{-1} \lambda_1 \mathbf{u}$ for $\lambda \notin \sigma(A)$,
$$\begin{align}
\psi(\lambda) &= \det(\lambda I_n - A + \lambda_1 \mathbf{uv}^T) \\
&= \det(\lambda I_n - A) \det(I_n + (\lambda I_n - A)^{-1} \lambda_1 \mathbf{uv}^T) \\
&= \varphi(\lambda) \det(I_n + (\lambda - \lambda_1)^{-1} \lambda_1 \mathbf{uv}^T) \\
&= \varphi(\lambda) \left( 1 + \frac{\lambda_1 \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{u}}{\lambda - \lambda_1} \right) = \frac{\lambda \varphi(\lambda)}{\lambda - \lambda_1} = \lambda \frac{\varphi(\lambda) - \varphi(\lambda_1)}{\lambda - \lambda_1} \quad \text{for} \quad \lambda \notin \sigma(A).
\end{align}$$

Thus, as $\lambda_1 \varphi'(\lambda_1) = \psi(\lambda_1)$, $\lambda_1$ will be a simple root of $\varphi(\lambda)$ if and only if $\psi(\lambda_1) \neq 0$. But, if $(A - \lambda_1 \mathbf{uv}^T) \mathbf{x} = \lambda_1 \mathbf{x}$ for some vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n$, then
$$
\lambda_1 \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v}^T (A - \lambda_1 \mathbf{uv}^T) \mathbf{x} = \lambda_1 \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{x} - \lambda_1 \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{x} = 0.
$$

Therefore, $A \mathbf{x} = \lambda_1 \mathbf{x}$ and hence, in view of step $3$, $\mathbf{x} = \alpha \mathbf{u}$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Thus,
$$
\alpha = \alpha \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{x} = 0.
$$

But this means that the null space of $A - \lambda_1 \mathbf{uv}^T$ is equal to zero and, consequently, $\psi(\lambda_1) \neq 0$, as needed to complete the proof of this step.

I found an interesting proof that shows that the Perron root in the Perron-Frobenius Theorem has multiplicity $1$. However, I'm stuck on the last part (last line): if the null space is trivial, how can the characteristic polynomial of matrix $2$ not be zero?
My attempt:
Since nullity involves trivial solution, the matrix is invertible and, therefore, the determinant of that matrix is non-zero, but how come the characteristic polynomial determinant is also non-zero as per proof in the last line?

This is clearly a typo. The author assumes that $(A-\lambda_1uv^T)x=\lambda_1 x$ and infers that $x$ must be zero. Therefore, the matrix that has a zero null space is not $A-\lambda_1uv^T$, but $A-\lambda_1uv^T-\lambda_1I$. Hence $\det(A-\lambda_1uv^T-\lambda_1I)\ne0$, i.e., $\psi(\lambda_1)\ne0$.

"hence, in view of step 3..." -- what is step 3?  Your text starts with a theorem statement then evidently step 4...  Was step 3 them first proving geometric multiplicity of $1$?  If so I can give you a nicer proof via symmetrization.

Yes i will include that part also @- user8675309

Yes i will include that part also @user8675309

Linear algebra in action
Book by Harry Dym

I have also mentioned the part (3) @user8675309

did you want me to post the symmetrization argument?  I find it a bit more intuitive (and it unlocks some other results) but the argument you posted seems to work after adjusting for the mentioned typo -- i.e. it means to argue that $\dim \ker \big (\lambda_1 I - (A -\lambda_1 \mathbf {uv}^T) \big) = 0$

Yes,Any proof which is more elegant is better @user8675309

Start by considering the special case where we have symmetry with left and right Perron vectors, i.e. suppose your irreducible non-negative matrix $C$ has $\mathbf v_1$ as its left and right Perron vector. (In applications this shows up with e.g. Doubly Stochastic matrices; this also implies $\lambda_1$ is the operator 2 norm of the matrix which we don't need here but that has very nice properties which can be useful elsewhere.)  Working over $\mathbb C$ and applying Schur Triangularization to $C$:
$V := \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}\mathbf v_1 & \mathbf v_2 &\cdots & \mathbf v_{n}\end{array}\bigg]$
$C = VRV^{-1} = VRV^{*} =V\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 &  \mathbf x_{m-1}^*\\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf R_{m-1} \end{bmatrix}V^* =V\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 &  \mathbf 0^T\\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf R_{m-1} \end{bmatrix}V^*$
note $\mathbf x_{m-1} = \mathbf 0$  because  $\lambda_1 \mathbf v_1^T = \lambda_1\mathbf v_1^* =\lambda_1\mathbf v_1^* C = \lambda_1\cdot \mathbf v_1^* + \sum_{j} x_j\cdot \mathbf v_j^*$
and the columns of $\mathbf V$ (or rows of $\mathbf V^*$) are linearly independent so every $x_j =0$
$\text{"step 3" }\implies 1=\dim \ker \big(\lambda I - B\big)=\dim \ker\begin{bmatrix} 0 &  \mathbf 0^T\\ \mathbf 0 & \lambda_1I_{m-1}-\mathbf R_{m-1} \end{bmatrix}$
$\implies \lambda_1I_{m-1}-\mathbf R_{m-1} $ has no zeros on its diagonal, i.e. $\lambda_1$ has algebraic multiplicity of $1$.
general case of irreducible $A$
First: homogenize the row sums of irreducible $A$ having right Perron vector $\mathbf u$
$B:=\big(D^{-1}AD\big)$  with $D := \text{diag}\big(\mathbf u\big)$ and
$ B\mathbf 1 = \big(D^{-1}AD\big)\mathbf 1=D^{-1}A\big(D\mathbf 1\big) = D^{-1}A\mathbf u = \lambda_1  D^{-1}\mathbf u = \lambda_1 \mathbf 1$
so the one's vector is the Perron vector for $B$.
Second:  symmetrize Perron vectors
$B$ has left Perron vector $\mathbf w$
$C:= \Gamma^\frac{1}{2} B \Gamma^\frac{-1}{2}$ with $\Gamma:= \text{diag}\big(\mathbf w\big)$
$C$ has $\mathbf z = \Gamma^\frac{-1}{2}\mathbf w = \Gamma^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf 1$ as the left and right Perron vector (check!).  Since $C$ and $A$ are similar $\lambda_1$ has the same algebraic multiplicity of $1$, i.e. the Perron root is simple.
remark:
I have taken it as obvious that positive diagonal similarity transforms do not alter non-negativity of a matrix or irreducibility.  Definitions vary for the latter term but one can check that if $P^{-1}CP$ is block lower triangular for some permutation matrix $P$ then so is $P^{-1}AP$; alternatively $I+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} A^k$ is a positive matrix so $I+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} C^k = \Sigma^{-1}\big(I+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} A^k\big)\Sigma$ is too.

could you give source material or reference,i am finding tough to understand the proof @user8675309

@WillSilva I don't know of one.  This is something I came up with on my own to streamline a lot of results I'd seen on Perron Frobenius theory.  The point is that in the special case of $ C \mathbf v_1=\lambda \mathbf v_1 = C^T \mathbf v_1 $ then the result should be obvious -- if that argument is not obvious to you then it's likely not the right proof for you.
